# Can I separate compile binary in opencl like this way?

Tags: kernel, opencl

```c
    cl_program prog_cl;;
    cl_program pprogram_head;
    std::ifstream srcFile("kernel.cl");
    string srcProg(istreambuf_iterator<char>(srcFile), (istreambuf_iterator<char>()));
    const char* src = srcProg.c_str();
    size_t src_length = srcProg.length();

    prog_cl = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, (const char**)&src,
        &src_length, &err);
    err = clCompileProgram(prog_cl, 1, &device, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    std::cout << "  clCompileProgram1: " << err;;
    char* programBinary = new char[1024];
    FILE* pf;
    size_t programBinarySize;
    
    clGetProgramInfo(prog_cl, CL_PROGRAM_BINARY_SIZES, sizeof(cl_device_id), &programBinarySize, NULL); 
    programBinary = ( char*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * programBinarySize);
    clGetProgramInfo(prog_cl, CL_PROGRAM_BINARIES, sizeof(unsigned char*), &programBinary, NULL);      
    
    fopen_s(&pf, "vec.bin", "w");
    fwrite(programBinary, 1, programBinarySize, pf);
    free(programBinary);
    fclose(pf);

    programBinarySize = readSource("vec.bin", &programBinary);
    cl_program prog[2];

    prog[0] = clCreateProgramWithBinary(context, 1, &device, &programBinarySize, (const unsigned char**)&programBinary, NULL, &err);
    std::cout << "clCreateProgramWithBinary" << err << std::endl;
    err = clCompileProgram(prog[0], 1, &device, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    std::ifstream srcFile_head("add.cl");
    string srcProg_head(istreambuf_iterator<char>(srcFile_head), (istreambuf_iterator<char>()));
    const char* src_head = srcProg_head.c_str();
    size_t src_length_head = srcProg_head.length();
    prog[1] = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, &src_head, &src_length_head, &err);
    err = clCompileProgram(prog[1], 1, &device,NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    std::cout << "clCompileProgramn3" << err;

    cl_program program = clLinkProgram(context, 1, &device, NULL, 2, prog, NULL, NULL, &err);
```

I always get cllinkprogram error.what is the right way to do this?I want compile a binary form disk.And Separate Compilation and Linking with clCompileProgram and clLinkProgram

Comment: What does your function `readSource()` look like? The name suggests it's for reading a text file, not a binary, so I'm wondering if it's perhaps corrupting the binary data.

Comment: Additionally, have you made sure none of the prior functions return errors? Not all error codes are logged, so your original source of error may be further up.